# Angular 4 - How to use currency pipe in input type

Tags: angular, html-input, angular-pipe, angular2-ngmodel

I have an HTML input:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="item.value" name="inputField" type="text" />
```

I want to format its value and use an existing pipe:

```
.... [(ngModel)]="item.value | currency:'USD':true" .....
```

Also I'm trying to use it the following way, but it's giving me desirable output for the first time and showing error while updating the field:

```
<input type="text" 
   [ngModel]="item.value | currency:'USD':true" 
   (ngModelChange)="item.value=($event)">
```

The above code leads to following error.

> ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '' for pipe 'CurrencyPipe'
>       at invalidPipeArgumentError (common.es5.js:2610)
>       at formatNumber (common.es5.js:3176)
>       at CurrencyPipe.webpackJsonp.../../../common/@angular/common.es5.js.CurrencyPipe.transform (common.es5.js:3350)
>       at LandingPageComponent.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/guest-handling/landing-page/landing-page.component.ts.LandingPageComponent.transformAmount (landing-page.component.ts:54)
>       at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (LandingPageComponent.html:38)
>       at handleEvent (core.es5.js:12014)
>       at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13475)
>       at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.es5.js:13063)
>       at dispatchEvent (core.es5.js:8607)
>       at core.es5.js:9218

Comment: Why the () around $event? Try without.

Comment: I think that's not matters is same as you use without ()

Answer (score 22):

Here is what worked just fine with currency pipe:

```
<input
  matInput 
  type="text"
  placeholder="Test Price"
  [ngModel]="testPrice | currency:'USD':'symbol':'2.2'"
  [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn:'blur'}"
  (ngModelChange)="testPrice=$event"
/>
```

Basically using the ngModelOptions to update on blur allows for the 0s not to be added while typing in the input field.

Comment: imo this is the cleanest and simplest solution

Answer (score 6):

I think this is a solution for you:

```
<input type="text" 
   [ngModel]="item.value | currency:'USD':true" 
   (ngModelChange)="item.value=currencyInputChanged($event)">
```

And then in your controller. Currency mark in from value in input:

```
  currencyInputChanged(value) {
    var num = value.replace(/[$,]/g, "");
    return Number(num);
  }
```

Comment: This *almost* works, but if you actually run it in the browser, it has unexpected behavior, which is due to the fact that the `CurrencyPipe` adds the extra `0`'s immediately, then starts adding the new numbers.

Comment: which version of angular do you have?

Comment: This won't work with any version, it's a problem with your approach to using `CurrencyPipe`, not Angular. Check out the second input in this link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-clr8se

Comment: Hey vincecampanale, I am using Angular 4

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to combine some answers with a little change like this -

HTML:

```
<input
  matInput 
  type="text"
  placeholder="Test Price"
  [ngModel]="testPrice | currency:'USD'"
  [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn:'blur'}"
  (ngModelChange)="updateCurrencyField($event)"
/>
```

TS:

```
updateCurrencyField(value: string): void {
  const onlyNumbers = value.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');
  this.valueChange.emit(Number(onlyNumbers));
}
```