# How to re-apply angular pipe on input

Tags: angular

I am trying to use a currency pipe in an input field that the user.  So if the user enters 1234, it will reformat to 1,234.00.

I've found a good solution to this here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50862298/1581924

This works the first time the user enters a number, but if the user re-types the same number, the input pipe is not applied the second time.

Example:

Type: 1234

Result: refomats to 1,234.00 (expected behavior)

Delete 1,234.00 and type 1234 again.

Result: input is not reformatted and left at 1234 (not expected behavior)

Example of code that exhibits the problem:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hnxyzs?file=app/app.component.html

Is there any way to force the pipe to be re-applied if the value is updated the the same value?

Comment: the reason is that value doesn't change, so it doesn't format it again, not sure about the solution

Comment: I think you have to create your own pipe formatter..

Comment: @RonakPatel the issue is not the pipe, it's how angular reports changes on ngModel

Comment: I actually tried to create my own pipe and set pure to false, which did not work.  I agree with @Reza, its related to the fact that angular doesnt think the model is updated, so doesnt re-run the pipe.  I am wondering if its possible to add something to (ngModelChange)="testPrice=$event" to manually trigger at re-evaluation

Comment: @sdparker `(ngModelChange)` will be fired when model is changed

Comment: ngModelChange does get fired, and the pipe actually gets evaluated, but the HTML dom element does not get updated. I suppose I could have the ngModelChange call a function that updates the dom element manually, but that seems like overkill

Answer (score 1):

Create custom pipe and chain with currency pipe.

**Try this:**

**component.html**

```
<input matInput type="text" placeholder="Test Price" [ngModel]="testPrice | mypipe | currency:'USD':'symbol':'2.2'" [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn:'blur'}" 
      (ngModelChange)="testPrice=$event"/>
```

**custom.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { CurrencyPipe } from '@angular/common';
@Pipe({
  name: 'mypipe'
})
export class MypipePipe  extends CurrencyPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    const val = value && value.split('$');
    const trans = val && val[1];
    return trans ? trans.replace(',', '') : value;
  }


}
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pgtdqb)

Comment: unfortunately still doesn't work.  Formats it the first time, but if I then retype same thing, leaves it unformatted.

Comment: Did you check the stackblitz?

Comment: @Chellappanவ stackblitz example has the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Going through your comments "`ngModelChange`" not firing or why it's not reformatting. The currency pipe accepts number and does not work if you pass string like `$555` or `555,555`.

If you type `555555` it turns into `$555,555.00` and if you try to remove `.00` the value of `price` is not updated because of the error, passed string to currency pipe. Also, if you remove `$` still it does not work as you have `,` comma and the value of price is not updated.

If you completely remove the value from input box and type new value. Should work fine.

Coming to your case:

**Typing `1234` which formats fine but if you delete and put `1234` again it does not reformat. It's because the value of price/ model is not changed. It was `1234` and it is `1234`. You just see different formats which does not reflect to your model. After removing `1234` click somewhere to update the price/ model value and type again the same number, and you will notice what's happening.**

Since you are using the currency pipe with input and binding model, you have to write a custom pipe or a method to convert your value to currency.

Answer (score 0):

Recalculate the value on blur

Define the following in your html:

```
<input matInput type="text" placeholder="Test Price" [ngModel]="testPrice | currency:'USD':'symbol':'2.2'" [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn:'blur'}" 
      (ngModelChange)="testPrice=$event" 
      (blur)="onBlurMethod()"/>
```

Define the following in your component:

```
  onBlurMethod() {
    this.testPrice = this.currencyPipe.transform(this.testPrice, '2.2')
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by running a change detection cycle with a different value.

```
<input matInput type="text" placeholder="Test Price" [ngModel]="testPrice | currency:'USD':'symbol':'2.2'" [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn:'blur'}" 
  (ngModelChange)="updateModel($event)"/>
```

Then in TS:

```
  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
  updateModel(event) {
     this.testPrice = null;
     this.cd.detectChanges();
     this.testPrice = event;
  }
```

I imagine that this would need some extra logic if you had formatting on null.

See example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6aqm8d?file=app/app.component.html